# Unable to log from windows form application

Tags: c#, log4net

I'm adding log to each of my functions in windows form application. I added logging configuration in a separate service and I added reference of this service into the windows app. Logging is working fine in service app but I don't know why I can't log from windows app ( no errors just nothing logged in the file).

Logger.cs

```
            Hierarchy hierarchy = (Hierarchy)LogManager.GetRepository();
            hierarchy.Root.RemoveAllAppenders();
            PatternLayout patternLayout = new PatternLayout();
            patternLayout.ConversionPattern = "%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline";
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();
            RollingFileAppender roller = new RollingFileAppender();
            roller.AppendToFile = true;
            roller.File = XMLParser.ReadTextNode(fileLocation, "Logfile");
            roller.Layout = patternLayout;
            roller.MaxSizeRollBackups = 0;
            roller.MaximumFileSize = "500MB";
            roller.StaticLogFileName = true;
            roller.ActivateOptions();
            hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(roller);
            hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.Info;
            hierarchy.Configured = true;
```

LogHelper.cs

```
 public static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(CLogger));

 public static void LogFile(string loglevel, string message)

{
                if (loglevel == "ERROR")
                {
                    logger.Error(message);
                }
}
```

Logging Example:

```
LogHelper.LogFile("ERROR", "file is not found");
```

Comment: `but I don't know why I can't log from windows app` are you getting any errors, can you describe "cant log from windows app"? One option is to put in a piece of code to write something out to the console/file to see if you're even getting to that routine... Also `WriteLog != LogFile` which may be your issue.

Comment: It is simple, I added something to log but when I open the file I found nothing. Sorry for the typo I edited the question

Comment: Are you actually checking the right file?   It's possible it's working perfectly, but you aren't looking at the right log file.

Comment: Yeah I checked, it is just this file

Comment: There's a call to a setup function that has to be made for log4net to work.  Perhaps that's not getting called?

Comment: @Duston I didn't get what   you said

Comment: @Duston yeah sure I added the setup in program.cs of the service